# Sorting by department id, list the manager names, department names of managers who manage entire departments

Tags: sql, oracle

Below are the relevant tables:

[image: tables]

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    mgr.first_name, mgr.last_name, d.department_name 
FROM 
    employees mgr
JOIN  
    employees e ON mgr.manager_id = e.employee_id
JOIN 
    departments d ON d.dept_id = mgr.dept_id
GROUP BY 
    mgr.first_name, mgr.last_name, mgr.dept_id, d.department_name
ORDER BY 
    mgr.dept_id;
```

But I'm getting too many results. I am not sure what else to try. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the expected output for your sample data. You say you are getting too many results but you don't tell us what you start with or what you should be getting so how can we answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want the manager rather than including all of their employees.

```sql
SELECT e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       d.department_name
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN departments d 
       ON ( d.manager_id = e.employee_id )
ORDER BY e.dept_id;
```

Then you want to join the `locations` table as the question asks for the "addresses, cities and states"; however, since this appears to be a homework question, I'll leave that for you to complete.